# Minecraft item filter that is changable

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-redstone

So I want to have a item filter that I can change using a button, so basically like a regular item filter and then I input a new item the old one will be burned or sent into a container, I have tried making it for days but couldn't come up for a design I tried unlocking the hopper for a small amount of time to let the old item out and then put the new item in with a dropper but it still doesn't work. Does anyone have a design or something?

Comment: There are certainly designs for something like this online, but the basic principle is just what you wrote. What goes wrong with your current design? Maybe it's easier to debug that than to come up with a completely new one.

Comment: Well I have somehing that semi works but not completely, I have two item filters next to each other and I have droppers facing to the hopper that contains the randomn items and the sort item and then I make a 1 tick pulse using the piston thingy into a two tick repeater that gets rid of the previous item and a bit later using repeaters the droppers will fire the new item into the sorters, but the sorter needs to have 1 of the item in the hopper that the comparator is observing and one in the bottom one so I need the dropper to fire twice but I do not know how to do that

Comment: Also two screenshots if that should give a better idea
1. https://cdn.acemavie.eu/images/2023-07-18_12.25.21.png
2. https://cdn.acemavie.eu/images/2023-07-18_12.25.24.png

Comment: You don't need two items if you just put another hopper below the bottom one. I didn't quite understand your entire explanation, was there another issue?